# Full-text search engine for my Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, full-text-search, windows-phone-8

I want to offline search for different text queries through bunch of local HTML files in my WP7.5+ application. I want the search to be full-functional, morphology-sensitive, creating snippets i.e. considering nearby words. Do you know any existing solutions or libraries that may help to create such engine?

P.S. A good example of what I want to get is [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/) for Win/Linux/Mac. Speaking about Win8 branches similarity, I hope it will be ported to WP some day.

Comment: [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). But I don't know whether it works on WP8 or not.

Comment: Above link is invalid. Check this [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)